# How to comparing pair of columns using udf in pyspark?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I Have Dataframe like below

```
+---+---+---+
| t1| t2|t3 |
+---+---+---+
|0  |1  |0  |
+---+---+---+
```

I want to compare each column with other column.

for example  `t1` column value `0` and `t2` column value is `1` the `t1 and t2` combination column is `1`.

we have to apply `logical oR` for all column pairs.

my expected output will be like below:

```
+----+---+---+---+
|t123| t1|t2 | t3|
+----+---+---+---+
|t1  |0  |1  |0  |
|t2  |1  |0  |1  |
|t2  |0  |1  |0  |
+----+---+---+---+
```

please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
cols=df.columns
n=len(cols)
df1=pd.concat([df]*n,ignore_index=True).eq(1)
df2= pd.concat([df.T]*n,axis=1,ignore_index=True).eq(1)
df2.columns=cols
df2=df2.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1|df2).astype(int)
```

Explanation:

1. Convert df1 into logical df as you need
2. Convert df2 into logical df as you need with transpose
3. Perform logical OR in both df

Output:

```
   t1  t2  t3
0   0   1   0
1   1   1   1
2   0   1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

For pyspark, you can create an empty df then insert it in loop based on columns. Below works not only 3 columns but also for more columns

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> 
>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), df.schema)
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+
| t1| t2| t3|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+

>>> df1 = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), df.schema)
>>> df1 = df1.select(F.lit('').alias('t123'), F.col('*'))
>>> df1.show()
+----+---+---+---+
|t123| t1| t2| t3|
+----+---+---+---+
+----+---+---+---+

>>> for x in df.columns: 
...     mydf = df.select([(F.when(df[i]+df[x]==1,1).otherwise(0)).alias(i) for i in df.columns])
...     df1 = df1.union(mydf.select(F.lit(x).alias('t123'), F.col('*')))
... 
>>> df1.show()
+----+---+---+---+
|t123| t1| t2| t3|
+----+---+---+---+
|  t1|  0|  1|  0|
|  t2|  1|  0|  1|
|  t3|  0|  1|  0|
+----+---+---+---+
```